# Running Gatling tests not showing testFile.log on IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, gatling, scala-gatling

We have an issue where whenever our Gatling performance tests are run the .log file that should generate at the root of the folder is not there.

This is my whole logback file if anyone able to help please.

```
<contextListener class="ch.qos.logback.classic.jul.LevelChangePropagator">
    <resetJUL>true</resetJUL>
</contextListener>

<appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <!-- <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
         <level>INFO</level>
     </filter> -->
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%-5level] %logger{15} - %msg%n%rEx</pattern>
        <immediateFlush>true</immediateFlush>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
    <file>testFile.log</file>
    <append>false</append>
    <!-- encoders are assigned the type
       ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder by default -->
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%-5level] %logger{15} - %msg%n%rEx</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<!-- uncomment and set to DEBUG to log all failing HTTP requests -->
<!-- uncomment and set to TRACE to log all HTTP requests -->
<logger name="io.gatling.http.engine.response" level="TRACE" />

<root level="WARN">
    <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
</root>
```

Thank you very much.

**Update**

It seems the issue may be with **IntelliJ itself** as noticed we can see the file when going directly to the finder.

[image]

Comment: Please check that file/extension isn't added to "Ignore files and folders" list in "Preferences | Editor | File Types"

Comment: When I search for the file using the search button (ctrl shift f wont do) I can find it and open it and then it does tell me it's ignored. However, it's not part of my gitignore list neither I can see it under File Types as it's what I have there. ```*.hprof;*.pyc;*.pyo;*.rbc;*.yarb;*~;.DS_Store;.git;.hg;.svn;CVS;__pycache__;_svn;vssver.scc;vssver2.scc;```

Comment: Could you please share idea.log ("Help | Show Log in...") after restarting IDE?

Comment: Sure. It's pasted as a gist here https://gist.github.com/francislainy/86f2aa8d5e7ce97bc08ec17734b04a57 .Thank you.

Comment: Please try to temporarily disable custom plugins:  Key Promoter X (2020.1.2), ANSI Highlighter (1.2.4), Rainbow CSV (1.3), Lombok (0.30-2020.1), HOCON (2020.1.0), Ideolog (201.0.22.0), Kotlin (1.3.72-release-IJ2020.1-1), .ignore (3.2.3.201), CSV Plugin (2.9.3), Scala (2020.1.27), Catdea (1.1.6), Docker (201.6668.113)

Comment: Yes, disabling the plugins fixed the issue. Even after reenabling them I can see still see the log files now. Thanks a million. PS: If you'd like to have this comment as an answer I'm happy to update and accept that to mark this issue as solved. Enjoy your day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disabling custom plugins should help. Seems one of configuration was corrupted.

Comment: Yeah, disabling, restarting and then enabling the plugins again helped me see the .log files again under the file tree. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There's a good chance the file is simply not generated where you expect it. Try setting an absolute path instead to verify.

Comment: Thank you. I've tried that too but even when I go Ctrl + F on the whole project I don't find the file so I think it's not being generated at all.

Comment: I think the issue must be with IntelliJ itself as noticed we can see the file when going direct inside the finder.